# How LaTeX format paragraph

Tags: formatting, tex-core

When I write a document, I get always `Underfull` and `Overflow` warnings. I know what do these warnings mean.

I want to know what LaTeX (TEX I guess) does to format a paragraph. I mean, how it decides where to break a line, for example. I have got an `Underfull` warning on paragraph I wrote (sorry I don't have it now); as a result, I got a part of the word `development` (`lopment`) written in the margin.

Why does LaTeX not wrote `deve-` in the first line and `lopment` in the next line?

Comment: TeX is usually able to hyphen `dev-el-op-ment`; if it doesn't, then something that you're not telling is happening: is it a part of a compound word?

Comment: Are you using the correct language on `babel`?  I've seen this behavior because people don't use the right hyphenation patterns for the language the are writing in.

Comment: Yes I have used the right package. @egreg How Tex decide how to hyphen a word?

Comment: Please, make an example with the code.

Comment: I don't have the code. Your comment helped me to understand why we get Underfull warnings. I didn't know that there are rules to hyphen.

Comment: @user230137 He wants the code to produce your document and be able to reproduce exactly your problem. You must have that code :) Starting from `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: @Manuel I don't have it. I have changed my paragraph and I don't remember what I wrote the first time.